# Stop scroll of a div on hover with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div with scrolling contents, I want to stop the scroll on hover but can't find a way to do it. Tried using mouseover function, don't know if it was the right way or not but that didn't work.

Here's what I have this far:

```js
window.verticalScroller = function($elem) {
    var top = parseInt($elem.css("top"));
    var temp = -1 * $('#verticalScroller > div').height();
    if (top < temp) {
        top = $('#verticalScroller').height()
        $elem.css("top", top);
    }
    $elem.animate({
        top: (parseInt(top) - 60)
    }, 1500, function() {
        window.verticalScroller($(this))
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#verticalScroller > div").each(function() {
        $(this).css("top", i);
        i += 60;
        window.verticalScroller($(this));
    });

});
```

```css
#verticalScroller {
  position: absolute;
  width: 52 px;
  height: 180 px;
  border: 1 px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#verticalScroller > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50 px;
  height: 50 px;
  border: 1 px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="verticalScroller">
   <div>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
   <div>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
   <div>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
   <div>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this with javascript:

```
<script>

function launchScroll() {
    if (window.verticalScroller != window.verticalScrollerProto)
        window.verticalScroller = window.verticalScrollerProto;

    var i = 0;
    $("#verticalScroller > div").each(function() {
        $(this).css("top", i);
        i += 60;
        window.verticalScroller($(this));
    });
}

window.verticalScrollerProto = function($elem) {
    var top = parseInt($elem.css("top"));
    var temp = -1 * $('#verticalScroller > div').height();
    if (top < temp) {
        top = $('#verticalScroller').height()
        $elem.css("top", top);
    }
    $elem.animate({
        top: (parseInt(top) - 60)
    }, 1500, function() {
        window.verticalScroller($(this))
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
        launchScroll();
    });

$('#verticalScroller').hover(
        function(){
            window.verticalScroller = function(){};
        },
        function(){
            launchScroll();
        }
    );
</script>
```

The idea is that the loop function is recursive and attached to a window variable, so we can just empty that entity to stop the loop. I'm populating it in the first place from a prototype so that its value is easy to restore.

Onmouseover, replace the function with an empty one.
Onmouseout, replace empty function with recursive one and restart the loop.

Comment: Yup this works good, thank you! Just need to change a thing that on resume of scroll, it should continue from where it left off and not from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `position: fixed` CSS attribute. Unless you have some scroll circumstances, this could be accomplished with pure CSS.

```
.hover-no-scroll:hover {
  position: fixed;
}
```